# How to assign a different configuration file during SSIS package runtime?

Tags: ssis

I am creating a dtsx package that I am running through a bat file. At design time, I created a package configuration that points to a specific location. When I am running the package at run-time, however, I am setting the ConfigFile to a package configuration in a different location. It appears, however, that the package is still running off of the configuration set at design time. Does any one know why this might happen? Any ideas on how I can get the package to run with this different configuration? The following is what I am running in my bat file.

```
dtexec.exe /f "mypackage.dtsx" /ConfigFile "[some_path]/newconfig.dtsConfig"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, then the order in which package configurations are applied in is as follows:

1. Design-time configurations
2. Run-time configurations (i.e. those specified by the /ConfigFile parameter
3. Design-time configurations again

Therefore any variables set in the design-time config cannot be changed using the /ConfigFile parameter.

The official solution to this is to change the path to the design-time configuration using the /Set parameter.

Details on this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500430.aspx

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use /Set to change the path to the design-time configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having different sets of .dtsconfig files per environment (DEV, QA, PRD) and to register them as Environment Variables on the machines using setx batch command to define the Variable name and file path.

By using the same Environment Variables names on all environments you will mitigate the need to specify the .dtsconfig file at runtime.